# Visual Studio 2013 + Boost library build and link problems

Tags: c++, boost, visual-studio-2013, build, linker

Im working on a project on visual studio 13, with 2 solutions:

1. Common: which holds all the third party libraries and some libraries implemented for use in the main solution.
2. Main solution: the main project.

In the main solution I wrote the following code:

```
#include "DiskMonitor.h"
#include <boost\filesystem.hpp>

void DiskMonitor::SetDiskPercentage(){
    boost::filesystem::space_info si = boost::filesystem::space("/opt/");
    this->diskPrctge = (si.capacity - si.free) / (double)si.capacity;
}
```

as you can tell im using boost\filesystem.hpp library. according to the boost documentation:

> Boost.Filesystem is implemented as a separately compiled library, so you must install binaries in a location that can be found by your linker. If you followed the Boost Getting Started instructions, that's already been done for you.

and:
[image]

However the boost filesystem sources are in the common solution:
[image]

what I want to do is build the sources as a part of the common solution and link my Main solution to the lib\dlls build output, via msvs 13 compiler and Visual studios solution properties. please help me accomplish that.

Comment: Why? The boost build system is complex and you'll spend a lot of time trying to replicate it. Why not just use the pre-built libraries?

Comment: @AlanBirtles How do I do that?

Comment: You've posted a screenshot of the relevant documentation in your question on how to build boost, if you don't want to build it yourself they are pre-built at https://sourceforge.net/projects/boost/files/boost-binaries/

Comment: @AlanBirtles After adding the pre-built libs to the project im getting a:"LNK1120: 9 unresolved externals" do you know why this happens?

Comment: No, what are the symbols?

Comment: error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "struct boost::filesystem::space_info __cdecl boost::filesystem::detail::space(class boost::filesystem::path const &,class boost::system::error_code *)" (?space@detail@filesystem@boost@@YA?AUspace_info@23@ABVpath@23@PAVerror_code@system@3@@Z) referenced in function "struct boost::filesystem::space_info __cdecl boost::filesystem::space(class boost::filesystem::path const &)" (?space@filesystem@boost@@YA?AUspace_info@12@ABVpath@12@@Z)

Comment: did you download the same version as you've used in your includes?

Comment: @AlanBirtles Well ive tried to compile it and it said im missin some version x of boost. ive added all the libs that were seen in the error and now im getting the "LNK1120: 9 unresolved externals" error